# block radio button

Tags: html, css

I want to make  block for radio

This is my code.

```html
   <label> Rating
     <input type="radio">great
     <input type="radio">wonderful 
   </label>
```

But it does not work correctly.

Comment: Do you mean you want the label on the left side, then on the right side "great" and "wonderful" below it?

Comment: yes in this order:

Comment: @Randalrand check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div style="display:flex; width: 120px;">
  <p style="flex:1">Rating</p>
  <div style="flex:1">
    <input type="radio">Good<br>
    <input type="radio">Great
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you mean something like this? You could also use a table to get the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

```css
label{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
   <p> Rating</p>
   <label for="radio1"><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiogroup1">great</label>
   <label for="radio2"><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radiogroup1">wonderful</label>
```

Comment: i want it block not inline block and use one label

Comment: @Randalrand Why want to use `display:block`?

Comment: to make it in separate lines

Answer (score 1):

**Only with html:**

```html
<label> Rating: </label>

<p>
  <input type="radio" name="rate" id="great">
  <label for="great">great</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="radio" name="rate" id="wonderful">
  <label for="wonderful">wonderful</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution to display as list.

```css
 label li {
    list-style:none;
    }
```

```html
     <label> Rating
       <li><input type="radio" name="group1">great</li>
       <li><input type="radio" name="group1">wonderful </li>
       </label>
```

Comment: Why would you use an inline element and add extra rules to make it block when you could just use an existing block element (`div`, `p`, etc).

Comment: @Znaneswar `span` is an inline-element, you are trying to make it as block. use block elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have do use any css here, you can create the structure using [block elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3).

Here you are trying to align a inline element in a block so you can use `p`, `div` or any other block element.

```css
/* outline focus */
label:focus, input:focus{
  outline: dotted 2px red;
}

/* No CSS to align the below elements */
```

```html
<label for="rating"> Rating</label>
<p><label for="great">great</label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="great"></p>
<p><label for="wonderful">wonderful</label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="wonderful"></p>
```